# Swiper Navigation And Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, swiper.js

A few days ago I asked help for a kind of website. Now I kinda made it using idangero's swiper but since I need the bullet to desappear and show my own linked menu I'm forced to create a div menu.

The problem is that when I slide with mouse or tapping with my phone the menu doesn't activate the name of the page on the menu that I'm visiting.

Any hint?

Here is my page: http://www.meowgraphix.it/prova

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Actually they are 2 different codes.
The real swiper demo page is this: [link]http://www.swiper.com.cn/demo/28-parallax.html[/link]

And as u can see it has bullets. So I made it look like this:

http://www.swiper.com.cn/api/function/2014/1218/109.html

But also as you can see it doesn't point on the menu on the bottom which slide I'm watching.

Comment: Sorry just fixed it ;=

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. The only thing is that hashes doesn't load the right panel but the main one automatically :'(